# Problemas al guardar imagen en php - failed to open stream: Permission denied php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy elaborando un formulario la cual suba archivos, y tengo un problema al momento de subir el archivo a mi directorio, y se guarda la ruta en mi bd, mas no llega a subirse a mi directorio, este es mi código:

```
if (isset($_FILES["expArchivo"]["tmp_name"])) {

                    $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 9999);
                    $fichero  = $_FILES["expArchivo"];
                    $ext = pathinfo($fichero["name"][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    $ruta = "view/public/archivos/DocQueja/" . $idUsuario . $aleatorio .'.' . $ext;

                    move_uploaded_file($fichero["tmp_name"][$i],  $ruta);
                }
```

$aleatorio .'.' . $ext; , esta parte es la que me genera problemas, al momento de concatenar ese punto ya no se logra subir el archivo y me sale el error failed to open stream, mas si lo quito ahí si se logra subir

Answer (score 0):

Hola recuerda subir toda la Url de tu path
Ejemplo  si utilizas Largon

Proyecto/view/public/archivos/DocQueja